# Как избежать ошибки дубликации атрибутов?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как устранить ошибку, которую выдает мне eslint?
Прикладываю код в песочнице
https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-diffie-pe69z?file=/src/views/Admin.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="admin">
        <h1>Редактирование</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="container">
            <AdminCarList
                    :carsFromApp="adminCars"
                    @change="onChangeSelectedCar"
            />
            <AdminCarWorks
                    :car="selectedCar"
                    :car-works="selectedCar.works"
                    @click="addWork"
                    @click="removeWork"
                    />
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import App from "../App";
    import AdminCarWorks from "../components/AdminCarWorks";
    import AdminCarList from "../components/AdminCarList";
    export default {
        name: 'app',
        data() {
            return {
                adminCars: App.data().cars,
                selectedCar: {
                    works: ''
                },
                work: {titleOfWork: '', cost: ''}
            }
        },
        components: {
            AdminCarList, AdminCarWorks
        },
        methods: {
            onChangeSelectedCar: function (selectedCarTitle) {
                this.selectedCar = this.adminCars.find(car => car.title === selectedCarTitle);
            },
            addWork: function (newWork) {
                this.work = newWork;
                this.selectedCar.works.push(this.work);
            },
            removeWork: function (work) {
                this.selectedCar.works = this.selectedCar.works.filter(carWorks => carWorks.work === work);
            }
        },
        props: ['carsFromApp', 'cars']
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ошибку и код нужно в сам вопрос вставлять

Comment: чтобы не было ошибки о дублирующихся атрибутах - не нужно дублировать атрибуты.

Comment: @Grundy а как тогда прослушивать одинаковые события из дочернего компонента?

Comment: Либо делать эти события неодинаковыми, например у тебя могут быть события onAdd, onRemove, либо определять внутри обработчика что пришло

Comment: @Grundy То есть, передавать это кастомное событие в $emit() с уникальным названием? Правильно понимаю?

Comment: именно так. Это же твое событие.

Comment: можно вызывать один метод, в другом

Comment: Ага. Принцип понял, осталось только реализовать. Я думал что такого сделать во вьюжс невозможно, однако я все еще так мало знаю и умею( Спасибо всем за помощь